# ListHeaderComponent Does Not Re-render When State Changes

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using FlatList with ListHeaderComponent.

```
<FlatList
        data={this.state[this.feeds].edges}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        onEndReached={this.onFetchFeeds}
        onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
        refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
        ListHeaderComponent={this.renderBody}

      />
```

I made a render ListHeaderComponent.

```
renderBody = () => {
                  if (this.props.body)
                    return this.props.body;
```

And `this.props.body` is delivered by a parent component.

```
<Feeds
    body={<View>
            { this.state.suggestions.slice(0, 3).map((channel, index) =>
                                                <ChannelSlot key={index} {...channel}/>)}
            { this.state.suggestions.length > 3 && !this.state.seeMore ?
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({seeMore: true})}>
                <Text style={styles.moreButton}>See More</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> : null}
            { this.state.seeMore && this.state.suggestions.slice(3, 15).map((channel, index) => <ChannelSlot key={index} {...channel}/>)}
    </View>}
/>
```

The problem is the component delivered to body is not re-rendered even though `this.state.seeMore` changes. It only re-renders when 'pull-to-refresh' was done on FlatList. Then it gets updated. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using a function for `ListHeaderComponent`, the value of that prop isn't changing even if the return value of that function might be different. So the `FlatList` doesn't know to re-render. Call the render function to produce a rendered element instead so any change in the return value of `renderBody()` will cause a re-render of the `FlatList` header.

```
<FlatList
        ...
        // note the function call here instead of passing the function itself
        ListHeaderComponent={this.renderBody()}

      />
```